# Frequency of black holes

Tags: black-holes, estimation, milky-way

How many black holes are considered to exist in the Milky Way.. and is there evidence of a single supermassive black hole at its center?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Did you do any research yourself on the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP showed no research efforts at all.

Comment: Excellent point, now I knowExcuse the lack

Comment: ..of research - given that the effect on other "nearby" stars point to a mass not able to be explained by anything other than a black hole - understood - so does this then mean that M31 would have a significantly more massive black hole and as an extension then IC1101 would have a the largest black hole of any known galaxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [Milky Way galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) contains about 100 billion stars (which is a lower-end estimate). Around 1 out of every 1000 stars is of appropriate mass to form a black hole. So a very rough estimate is 100 million stellar-mass black holes in the Milky Way.

As for the [supermassive black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole), they are found at the center of nearly every massive galaxy, and there is indeed one at the center of the Milky Way, corresponding with the location of [Sagittarius A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*).

Hope this helps!